# Generate ARGV from string

Tags: perl, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a setup where a Perl program would like to rerun itself with slightly modified command line arguments. In order to avoid starting up the Perl interpreter twice (user response time is important) using for example a `system` call, I would like to parse the new command line into `ARGV` directly, and then rerun myself with the new `ARGV` array.

The question is then: Is there a CPAN module that can parse a command line string into an ARGV array? (That is: do the usual word splitting and quote removals)..

Here is a first brute force attempt:

```
sub parse_string_arg {
    my ($line) = @_;

    my $reg = qr/( (?: " (?: [^"\\]++ | \\")*+") | # Item in "" with possible escaped "
                 (?: [^"\s]\S*+) )/x; # Item that is not in double quotes

    my $reg2 = qr/(?: (?<![\\])" | \\(?="))/x
      ;  # a quote with no backslash in front of it, or a backslash with a quote behind

    my @a = map { $_ =~ s/$reg2//g; $_ } # remove quotes and backslashes
      $line =~ /$reg/g;  # extract arguments

    return \@a;
}
```

Note: This does not handle strings in single quotes yet..

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sobrique It is a little bit complicated to explain, but you can think of it as running an alias command..

Comment: Thing is - there's rarely a need to redo argument list parsing, because ... they're a mechanism to pass 'stuff' into a command when being executed externally. E.g. when I run your perl script from my command line. If the script is calling itself, I simply don't understand why you need to do that.

Comment: @Sobrique Ok, don't worry :) Trust me it is necessary, but would take too long to explain here..

Comment: What do you mean by "user response time"? The actual performance in wall clock time? If you have a script where forking and `exec`uting the script again slows the performance noticeably, then something seems to be wrong. Either the parent script continues to do something very hard (a loop?) or you fork hundreds of iterations. If it is neither but just the hardware having a problem with running more than one interpreter, you should not be running Perl on it in the first place. Then again, any modern smart-watch probably can run dozens of instances of Perl with little problems...

Comment: @DeVadder It is working together with bash completion scripts, and there are lot's of code.. a difference of a 1/10 of a second matters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While i agree with the comment of Sobrique that it seems unlikely that this is the best way to solve your underlying problem: Yes such a module appears to exist. At least this comes up when searching for "parse commandline" on metacpan.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CommandLine

I did not test it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it possible to modify `@ARGV` from within the Perl script inside the `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {

    @ARGV = map s/regex/replace/r, @ARGV ;  # Transform
    push @ARGV, 'new', 'arguments';         # Add stuff
    shift @ARGV;
}

# @ARGV now changed
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have to parse the string.. (The string is generated later, after the BEGIN has finished)

Comment: You can modify `@ARGV` anywhere, not just in a `BEGIN` block. That can be used if you really need to make your script as unreadable to the uninitiated as possible, allowing you to use stuff like `pop` and `shift` without specifying an array even while outside of a subroutine (where they would default to `@_` instead of `@ARGV`, adding to the obfuscation ^^).